# HackHands Satellizer example - unexpected token issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm using this HackHands example to get started on Satellizer and stuck on running the express server-
https://hackhands.com/building-instagram-clone-angularjs-satellizer-nodejs-mongodb/

Here is my Server.js-

```
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var express = require('express');
var jwt = require('jwt-simple');
var moment = require('moment');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var path = require('path');
var request = require('request');

var config = require('./config');

var User = mongoose.model('User', new mongoose.Schema({

   instagramId: { type: String, index: true },
   email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true },
   password: { type: String, select: false },
   username: String,
   fullname: String,
   picture: String,
  accesstoken: String
 }));
mongoose.connect(config.db);

var app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

function createToken(user){
  var payload = {
   exp: moment().add(14, 'days').unix(),
    iat: moment().unix(),
    sub: user._id
  };
  return jwt.encode(payload, config.tokenSecret);
}


function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (!(req.headers &amp;amp;&amp;amp; req.headers.authorization)) {
return res.status(400).send({ message: 'You did not provide a JSON Web Token in the Authorization header.' });
  }

  var header = req.headers.authorization.split(' ');
  var token = header[1];
  var payload = jwt.decode(token, config.tokenSecret);
  var now = moment().unix();

  if (now &amp;gt; payload.exp) {
    return res.status(401).send({ message: 'Token has expired.' });
  }

  User.findById(payload.sub, function(err, user) {
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).send({ message: 'User no longer exists.' });
    }

   req.user = user;
    next();
  })
}


app.post('/auth/login', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, '+password', function(err, user) {
if (!user) {
  return res.status(401).send({ message: { email: 'Incorrect email' } });
}

bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, function(err, isMatch) {
  if (!isMatch) {
    return res.status(401).send({ message: { password: 'Incorrect password' } });
  }

  user = user.toObject();
  delete user.password;

  var token = createToken(user);
  res.send({ token: token, user: user });
});
  });
});

app.post('/auth/signup', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, existingUser) {
if (existingUser) {
  return res.status(409).send({ message: 'Email is already taken.' });
}

var user = new User({
  email: req.body.email,
  password: req.body.password
});

bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
  bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
    user.password = hash;

    user.save(function() {
      var token = createToken(user);
      res.send({ token: token, user: user });
    });
  });
});
  });
});

app.post('/auth/instagram', function(req, res) {
  var accessTokenUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token';

  var params = {
client_id: req.body.clientId,
redirect_uri: req.body.redirectUri,
client_secret: config.clientSecret,
code: req.body.code,
grant_type: 'authorization_code'
  };

  // Step 1\. Exchange authorization code for access token.
  request.post({ url: accessTokenUrl, form: params, json: true }, function(error, response, body) {

// Step 2a. Link user accounts.
if (req.headers.authorization) {

  User.findOne({ instagramId: body.user.id }, function(err, existingUser) {

    var token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    var payload = jwt.decode(token, config.tokenSecret);

    User.findById(payload.sub, '+password', function(err, localUser) {
      if (!localUser) {
        return res.status(400).send({ message: 'User not found.' });
      }

      // Merge two accounts.
      if (existingUser) {

        existingUser.email = localUser.email;
        existingUser.password = localUser.password;

        localUser.remove();

        existingUser.save(function() {
          var token = createToken(existingUser);
          return res.send({ token: token, user: existingUser });
        });

      } else {
        // Link current email account with the Instagram profile information.
        localUser.instagramId = body.user.id;
        localUser.username = body.user.username;
        localUser.fullName = body.user.full_name;
        localUser.picture = body.user.profile_picture;
        localUser.accessToken = body.access_token;

        localUser.save(function() {
          var token = createToken(localUser);
          res.send({ token: token, user: localUser });
        });

      }
    });
  });
} else {
  // Step 2b. Create a new user account or return an existing one.
  User.findOne({ instagramId: body.user.id }, function(err, existingUser) {
    if (existingUser) {
      var token = createToken(existingUser);
      return res.send({ token: token, user: existingUser });
    }

    var user = new User({
      instagramId: body.user.id,
      username: body.user.username,
      fullName: body.user.full_name,
      picture: body.user.profile_picture,
      accessToken: body.access_token
    });

    user.save(function() {
      var token = createToken(user);
      res.send({ token: token, user: user });
    });
  });
}
  });
});

     app.get('/api/feed', isAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
  var feedUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed';
  var params = { access_token: req.user.accessToken };

  request.get({ url: feedUrl, qs: params, json: true }, function(error, response, body) {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
  res.send(body.data);
}
  });
});

app.get('/api/media/:id', isAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
  var mediaUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/' + req.params.id;
  var params = { access_token: req.user.accessToken };

  request.get({ url: mediaUrl, qs: params, json: true }, function(error, response, body) {
if (!error &amp;amp;&amp;amp; response.statusCode == 200) {
  res.send(body.data);
}
  });
 });

app.post('/api/like', isAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
  var mediaId = req.body.mediaId;
  var accessToken = { access_token: req.user.accessToken };
  var likeUrl = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/' + mediaId + '/likes';

  request.post({ url: likeUrl, form: accessToken, json: true }, function(error, response, body) {
if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
  return res.status(response.statusCode).send({
    code: response.statusCode,
    message: body.meta.error_message
  });
}
res.status(200).end();
  });
});


app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
    });
```

And here is the error log when I run npm start cmd-

```
1 verbose cli [ 'node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
```

2 info using npm@2.7.5

3 info using node@v0.12.2

4 verbose node symlink /usr/local/bin/node

5 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]

6 info prestart instagram-server@0.0.0

7 info start instagram-server@0.0.0

8 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true

9 info instagram-server@0.0.0 Failed to exec start script

10 verbose stack Error: instagram-server@0.0.0 start: `node server.js`

10 verbose stack Exit status 1

10 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.

(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:213:16)
10 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:110:17)

10 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.

(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:14:12)

10 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)

```
10 verbose stack     at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)

10 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)

11 verbose pkgid instagram-server@0.0.0

12 verbose cwd /Users/nshrivastava/Desktop/instagram/server

13 error Darwin 14.3.0

14 error argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"

15 error node v0.12.2

16 error npm  v2.7.5

17 error code ELIFECYCLE

18 error instagram-server@0.0.0 start: `node server.js`

18 error Exit status 1

19 error Failed at the instagram-server@0.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.

19 error This is most likely a problem with the instagram-server package,

19 error not with npm itself.

19 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:

19 error     node server.js

19 error You can get their info via:

19 error     npm owner ls instagram-server


19 error There is likely additional logging output above.

20 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I always get this error on the terminal-
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3

Not sure what I'm missing here. Can anyone help?

My package.json is pasted below-

```
{
```

"name": "instagram-server",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.0.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.8.1",
    "cors": "^2.4.2",
    "express": "^4.9.0",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.2.0",
    "moment": "^2.8.3",
    "mongoose": "^3.8.17",
    "request": "^2.44.0"
  }

```
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem while running the express server while following this tutorial. All I did was removed the `&amp;`

Change

`if (!(req.headers &amp;amp;&amp;amp; req.headers.authorization))`

To

`if (!(req.headers && req.headers.authorization))`

You would also need to change it for all the subsequent functions that has `&amp;` in it.

Comment: Ah! Ok. This is really bad.. I have spent days trying to figure this out and thought this &amp was intentional :D. Let me check your solution and work this out. Thanks a lot. Will update this thread.

Comment: Thanks@ That worked. I am just working on some other issues on this hackhands example. Will ask you in case I'm stuck.